# How to create jasper reports in JSP and Java code

Tags: jasper-reports

I know how to design jasper report in jaspersoft iReport Designer.

I dont know how the designed report can bring to front end (web browser).

Please send me related links.

I know little bit JSP.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to integrate your reports with your web application.

[Refer this link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/embedding-using-http-api)

Also [Refer this link](http://www.defteam.com/five-different-levels-of-embedding-jasper-reports-server-bi-into-any-custom-web-application/)

[Refer this link](http://javaknowledge.info/calling-jasper-report-from-java-web-application-using-jsp/) for integration using java web application.

The simple way is to embed the jasperserver page in your web application using iFrame tag.

**Note: One major thing is that you have to deploy your reports to your JasperServer**